# Postgres joining data onto inserted generated IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, generated-columns

In postgres, I want to insert multiple rows into a first table, and then use the generated identities to insert multiple rows into a second table. Is there a way to join the returning IDs with my data?

I have the following code snippet, in which I first insert new dividends into the inserted table, and then use those generated IDs to insert into the dividend table.

```sql
WITH inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO transaction (transaction_date, mutation)
    SELECT transaction_date, mutation FROM new_dividends
    RETURNING transaction_id
)
INSERT INTO dividend (transaction_id, effect)
SELECT transaction_id, effect FROM inserted;
```

This does not work, because in the second insert, the effect should be selected from new_dividends, as it is not present in the returning statement.

EDIT: The transaction_id gets generated in transaction, so it is not selected from new_dividends. Thus there is no common unique column between the two resultsets.

Comment: Yes, you can join your `inserted` CTE with any other table, or a list of values. Use any `join` you find appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact the you are selecting from a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) doesn't stop you from using any [join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) you want: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5MZ6EfhJ):

```sql
WITH inserted AS (
    INSERT INTO transaction (transaction_date, mutation)
    SELECT transaction_date, mutation FROM new_dividends
    RETURNING transaction_id, transaction_date, mutation
)
INSERT INTO dividend (transaction_id, effect)
SELECT transaction_id, effect FROM inserted NATURAL JOIN new_dividends;
```

```
table "transaction";
```

| transaction_id | transaction_date | mutation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 59b0f892-9c7b-4d00-b2c0-736169290221 | 2023-10-31 15:15:46.863376+00 | mutation1 |

```
table new_dividends;
```

| transaction_date | mutation | effect |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-31 15:15:46.863376+00 | mutation1 | effect1 |

```
table dividend;
```

| transaction_id | effect |
| --- | --- |
| 59b0f892-9c7b-4d00-b2c0-736169290221 | effect1 |

Comment: You should normally alias your tables and specify which column comes from which one. With a `natural join`, it's clear `inserted` and `new_dividends` share a `transaction_id` so they both having that column doesn't pose a conflict, and you already said `effect` isn't present in `inserted` - so it's also clear it should come from `new_dividends`. If they have more more columns in common, you might want to switch to a regular `inner` or `left join` with explicit join conditions.

Comment: I see I made an error in my code snippet. Transaction_id is not present in new_dividends as it is generated in transaction. So I have no join condition, as the resultsets have no common columns. Is something like this still possible?

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. Still, makes no difference: you can return the two columns that *are* shared and `natural join` the `inserted` CTE on them. I've updated both the answer and the demo link in it